# Connecting to google big query through Java client API

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I have a problem while I try to access big query through Java API from a Java application in my desktop. Code is:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.BigqueryScopes;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.GetQueryResultsResponse;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.QueryRequest;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.QueryResponse;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableCell;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class GettingStarted {

  public static Bigquery createAuthorizedClient() throws IOException {
    HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(transport, jsonFactory);

    if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
      credential = credential.createScoped(BigqueryScopes.all());
    }

    return new Bigquery.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName("Bigquery Samples")
        .build();
  }

  private static List<TableRow> executeQuery(String querySql, Bigquery bigquery, String projectId)
      throws IOException {
    QueryResponse query =
        bigquery.jobs().query(projectId, new QueryRequest().setQuery(querySql)).execute();

    // Execute it
    GetQueryResultsResponse queryResult =
        bigquery
            .jobs()
            .getQueryResults(
                query.getJobReference().getProjectId(), query.getJobReference().getJobId())
            .execute();

    return queryResult.getRows();
  }

  private static void printResults(List<TableRow> rows) {
    System.out.print("\nQuery Results:\n------------\n");
    for (TableRow row : rows) {
      for (TableCell field : row.getF()) {
        System.out.printf("%-50s", field.getV());
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner sc;
    if (args.length == 0) {
      sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    } else {
      sc = new Scanner(args[0]);
    }
    String projectId="glassy-land-140915";

    Bigquery bigquery = createAuthorizedClient();

    List<TableRow> rows =
        executeQuery(
            "SELECT corpus as unique_words "
                + "FROM [bigquery-public-data:samples.shakespeare] LIMIT 10",
            bigquery,
            projectId);

    printResults(rows);
  }
}
```

#### Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:283)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:384)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:868)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
at GettingStarted.executeQuery(GettingStarted.java:38)
at GettingStarted.main(GettingStarted.java:73)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was firewall in the network preventing from accessing google cloud. Used a different network and fetched the results.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a proxy with you java client 
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=  -Dhttp.proxyPort= ….  -jar you_bg_client.jar